# how can I make sure that the last tag in my div is always a <br />? caret issue (bug?) in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable, caret

I have a `contentEditable div` that can contain several `span` and `br` tags.

**Desired functionality**: when the user presses `return`, a new line is added and the caret is correctly placed in the new line, like in this first screenshot:

[image]

**The issue I'm facing**: if the last tag is not a `br` (look at the very last br tag in the first screenshot), when the user presses `return` to add a new line the cursor is for some reason misplaced (somewhere between the first line and the second line, see second screenshot). After hitting `return` again and deleting the previous new line or by starting to type in, the caret eventually is correctly placed. Currently the last `br` tag is lost only if the user selects all text (`ctrl + a`) and deletes all contents.

[image]

To avoid having problems I'd just append a br tag at the end of my div (unless there is already one). Otherwise I'm happy to try out any other solution. How can I fix this behave?

**Things I've tried**:

```
var brTag = document.createElement("br");

if (textBox.lastChild != brTag) {
    $(textBox).append("<br />");
}
```

and...

```
if (textBox.lastChild != "<br></br>") {
    $(textBox).append("<br />");
}
```

Neither worked!

Comment: Doesn't last child return an object...you want to gets it's inner content as a string to do the compare

Comment: Note that `<br>` does not need or use a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: Your research should stay in the question, and answers don't belong in the question

Comment: I saw it many times on the project I'm working on and I wasn't sure about why. I should have researched it. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: ... Don't put the solution in your questions, you're shortchanging the work that the answerer provided

Comment: I already selected his answer as the solution, which anyway contains a mistake: `==` should be `!=`. I added his name for credits. Is that enough?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que

Comment: you've essentially removed the most important part of your question and replaced it with the answer... and the answer doesn't belong in your question. That makes your question less useful for future users with the same problem. How can they know they have the same problem if you've removed all references to it?

Comment: I put the question back to its original state. If the answer has a mistake how can I point it out to the future users? It's my comment in the answer enough?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167887/discussion-between-devamat-and-kevin-b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First attempt does not work because `"<br></br>"` is the string representation of the last child, but it's actually a complex object which not equates to a string.

Second attempt does not work because you are comparing to a newly created element, which is not equal to any other element.

What you want is to compare `tagName` property of yout `lastChild`.
Try that:

```
if (textBox.lastChild.tagName != 'BR') {
    $(textBox).append("<br />");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my obvious mistakes. I tried your code but it keeps adding `br` tags even if `console.log(textBox.lastChild.tagName);` it's actually `BR`.

Comment: Silly me... just change `==` to `!=`